# Persistent bookmarks to particular Gmail accounts

Tags: browser, gmail, bookmarks, url

At work, I like to keep two Gmail tabs open: one showing my personal account, the other showing my work account.

I created bookmarks for the two accounts by copying the URL.  My personal account's URL was

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/
```

and my work account URL was

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/
```

This worked well for a while, but eventually I logged out of both accounts and apparently logged back in in the opposite order that I did intially, because my personal mail bookmark started taking me to my work account, and vice versa.  It seems that the final component in those URLs is some kind of non-persistent log-in-order index.

Is there any way to bookmark my accounts in a way that persists across logouts and logins, regardless of order?

Comment: Possible "cross-site duplicate" from [webapps.se] : [Is it possible to bookmark a Google calendar or inbox for a specific account?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/86559/88163)

Comment: Another possible "cross-site duplicate" from [webapps.se] : [Can I form a direct URL to a particular Gmail account?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/18959/88163)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following works:

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/?authuser=YOUR_EMAIL@gmail.com

And here is some text to fill the 30 character minimum. The URL doesn't count for whatever reason.

Comment: In my experience this does work, but only if you've already signed in to the desired accounts manually at least once for each machine you're using. Trying to get to my work inbox this way on my new PC would just redirect me to my personal inbox (which I've authorized earlier). Only when I've authorized my work account through "Add account" did the direct link work.

Comment: Thanks! It also works for Google Sheets, etc

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to create a specific shortcut for each account with the following URL (all on one line).

```
https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLoginAuth?continue=http://mail.google.com/gmail&service=mail&Email=LOGIN
```

Replace `LOGIN` with the email address of the gmail account you want the shortcut to go to. You will be taken to the sign-in screen for that account.

It is possible to add the password to the URL for automatic sign-in, but I do not recommend it because it leaves your password exposed to all who see the URL. But if you want to create a link with the password, add `&Passwd=PASSWORD&null=Sign+in` to above link after `LOGIN` and change `PASSWORD` to your actual password.

```
https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLoginAuth?continue=http://mail.google.com/gmail&service=mail&Email=LOGIN&Passwd=PASSWORD&null=Sign+in
```

Comment: This is useful, but I don't want to have to supply my password every time I use the bookmark.

Comment: I added the use of the password.

Comment: The top URL doesn't work IME, it just goes to main account.